# Best and easiest way to run a console application "job"

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a .NET console app that I'd like to run every minute. The console app retrieves some data from a MongoDB via API, iterates through them and makes some changes to data.

What would be the best way to do this? I know about Windows services but never worked with them. And I also don't know if it's the best idea to have the console app running all the time with a while loop.

Comment: Use [Windows Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page).

Comment: You can schedule a job which will run the console application on specified schedule.

Comment: A Windows service would be a good option to run your .NET console app every minute as a background process

Comment: You can also run as windows service and the sleep the thread for some time after every run.

Comment: you also can use packages like [Quarzt](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) or [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)